# Error: The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner in dart and I am trying to make a quiz game application where I use some widgets to get questions and answer options on the screen. The error that I am facing is **"The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'"**
Here are some snippets of my code:-

1. This is a list of Maps<String, Object> , I am storing questions and their answer options in this variable.

```
var questions = [
      {
        'questionText': 'What is your favourite season?',
        'answers': [
          'Summer',
          'Monsoon',
          'Winter',
        ]
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'What is your favourite color?',
        'answers': [
          'Black',
          'Green',
          'Blue',
        ]
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'What is your favourite food?',
        'answers': [
          'Chicken',
          'Kebab',
          'Biryani',
        ]
      },
    ];
```

2. This is where I call the Question and Answer Widget.

```
body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(questions[_questionsIndex]["questionText"]),
            ...{questions[_questionsIndex]['answers'] as List<String>}
                .map((answer) {
              return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer); //**ERROR**
            }).toList(),
          ],
        ),
```

The error appears on the statement : return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);

3. This is how my Answer Widget Class looks like:

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectAnswer;
  final String answerText;

  Answer(this.selectAnswer, this.answerText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.blue,
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        child: Text(answerText,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            )),
        onPressed: () {
          selectAnswer();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**What is the meaning of this error and why does it appear?
How can I fix this error?**

Thank you!

Comment: Error itself is well explanatory: "The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'". That means somewhere in the code you are assigning List type variable to String type variable. The good part is, we know the error line. At the error line, you are calling your Answer() function, which has 2 parameters, where 2nd parameter is of string type. But, while calling this function, you have given a List type variable "answer" (which is of type List<string>). Here your parameter assignment is being failed. Sorry, I don't know Dart, but this is basic rule of coding.

Answer (score 4):

if you mean:
The argument type 'List<String?>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String?>'.

I solve this issue with a single line, you can get List<String?> from List<String?>?

```
List<String?>? mylist = ['data1','data2'];
List<String?> mylist2 = List<String>.from(mylist);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your second code block. For a list of string, you should use just `List` type Instead of `List<String>` type.

You code would be like:

```
body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(questions[_questionsIndex]["questionText"]),
            ...{questions[_questionsIndex]['answers'] as List}
                .map((answer) {
              return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer); //**ERROR**
            }).toList(),
          ],
        ),
```

I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: I made the changes stated by you and also had to change the type of answerText variable to dynamic in my Answer widget class, In order to run the code but when I debug on my phone, Pixels overflow. Error statement:  **"Exception caught by rendering library: A RenderFlex overflowed by 99238 pixels on the bottom."**

Comment: Use Expanded instead of container in your Widget build function.

Comment: If this solution removes the "The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" error, then try wrapping your Column in a SingleChildScrollView to fix the RenderFlex overflowed warning

Answer (score 0):

You could try especifying the type of your main list with `List<Map<String,dynamic>>`

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> questions = [
  {
    'questionText': 'What is your favourite season?',
    'answers': [
      'Summer',
      'Monsoon',
      'Winter',
    ]
  },
  {
    'questionText': 'What is your favourite color?',
    'answers': [
      'Black',
      'Green',
      'Blue',
    ]
  },
  {
    'questionText': 'What is your favourite food?',
    'answers': [
      'Chicken',
      'Kebab',
      'Biryani',
    ]
  },
];
```

I tried to assing the element to a `List<String>` and every works

```
var a = questions[1]['answers'];
List<String> b = a;
print(b);
```

Comment: thanks for your input, but I am still getting the same error: **"type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'"**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using List change it to var, it worked for me and the error disappeared is dynamic and works perfectly. This is my code below:

```
class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {

  var scoreKeeper = [
    Icon(
      Icons.check,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.check,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'This is where the question text will go.',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: (){

              },
              child: Text('True'),
              // color: Colors.white,
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child:TextButton(
              onPressed: (){

              },
              // color: Colors.white,
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
              ),
              child: const Text('False'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: scoreKeeper,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also Icon on the List :

List<Icon> scoreKeeper = [];